# Cypress: Multiple Domains or Origins (Google Sign In) Testing

Tags: iframe, cypress, google-signin

The webpage I am automating has a Google Sign in option. All elements from this Google sign in option (like the 'Sign in with Google' button embedded in the webpage being tested) are inside an iframe.

[image]

I need to click this Google sign in button in order to shift to google sign in page and provide the needed credentials in order to sign in on my own webpage:

[image]

Note that from my webpage URL, after clicking the google button, it will be redirected to Google sign in page.

The problem is, I am getting this error after multiple attempts of locating and testing the iframe, its buttons and while allowing cypress to access another google sign in page from my webpage:

[image]

I have 2 things that I have tried already. One is to use the iframe plugin provided in this document: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/  (see Bonus: cypress-iframe plugin)

[image]

My sample script:

```
  login(loginName, password) {
    cy.visit('https://website.com/');
    cy.frameLoaded('iframe');
    cy.iframe().find('.loginGoogleButton').click();
  }
```

Second is to use cy.origin(). This is the latest support or feature from cypress in accessing and testing with multiple origins and domains.

See document: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2022/04/25/cypress-9-6-0-easily-test-multi-domain-workflows-with-cy-origin/

See youtube demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fohrq5GZSD8&t=129s

My sample script:

```
 cy.origin('https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/.....', () => {
      cy.xpath('.loginGoogleButton').click();
      cy.xpath('.googleEmailInputBox').type(googleEmail, { log: false });
      cy.xpath('.googleEmailPassword').click();
    })
```

But either still, error is still the same. Do we have any workaround for this?

Basically I just need to locate and click that embedded Google Sign in button from an iframe on my webpage then enter the needed google credentials then successfully log in in my own webpage.

i am using Cypress 12.12 (latest version)

Note that I already tried configuring my cypress.config.ts:

```
chromeWebSecurity: false,
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @shrhawk sadly, still no solution